# Prove that $\ker(AB) = \ker(A) + \ker(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove the following:
Let $A$ and $B$ be two commutative square matrices ($AB=BA$) over a commutative field such that $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\ker(A)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(B)=\ker(B)$.
Then $\ker(AB) = \ker(A) + \ker(B)$.

$(\operatorname{Im}(A)=\{ y ~|~ y=Ax $ for any vector $x \}$ and $\ker(A) = \{x ~|~ Ax=0\})$

Remark that $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\ker(A) \Rightarrow A^2=0$.
It is quite obvious to show that $\ker(A) + \ker(B) \subset \ker(AB)$, the reciprocal is the problem.

By advance, thank you for your help.

I forgot to precise that $A\ne B$. Is t still impossible?

Answer (score 2):

It is not right: take $A=B$, then $\ker(AB)=\ker(A^2) = V$, but $ker(A) + ker(B) = ker(A)$.